# Verify if process is running in remote server

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using paramiko to start a process in remote server.
With below code even if process is getting started or not ,it's printing 'not able to start'.
Not able to figure out issue here.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("{0}/minidiameterd -f {0}/BasicDiam1".format(minidiam_path))
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("pgrep minidiameterd")
output = stdout.readlines()
if not output:
    print "Not able to start minidiameterd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
output  = stdout.read.splitlines()
```